# can Clear-Content be equivalent to bash 'truncate'?

Tags: bash, filesystems, logging, powershell

This could be off-topic, if so my apologies; please re-direct me to the correct StackExchange site.

Can `Clear-Content file.log` be used in Powershell, on a Windows Server environment to empty a gigantic file occupying too much disk space without having to stop the IIS process that's writing on said log file?
In other words, is there a simple, concise, Pwsh cmdlet that operates in a similar fashion as any of the following BASH commands?

- `truncate -s 0 file.log`
- `cat /dev/null > file.log`
- `: > file.log`

Comment: These bash commands fail when your running program has an open file descriptor:
It will continue writing on tha hard disk, unaware of the changed system settings. You won't get your space back until the program is restarted.

Comment: having used `> catalina.out` which is more or less equivalent to the listed BASH commands, I know disk space can be recuperated. However I was mostly interested in the Powershell cmdlet on a proper Windows Server 2019 VM.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Clear-Content file.log be used in Powershell, on a Windows Server environment to empty a gigantic file occupying too much disk space without having to stop the process that's writing on said log file?

No. By default Windows will not let you truncate a file that is in use. (This is the same behaviour you see if you attempt to delete or rename a file that is in use.) This can be changed if the application programmer chose not to lock the file for writing.

In contrast, using a Linux-based OS, the `bash` commands will operate on the same NTFS filesystem, allowing you to truncate a file that is currently open for writing. (But not through Cygwin, as that uses the same Windows interface as above, which restricts these operations.)

I can't test `Clear-Content` under Powershell on a Linux-based system because I don't have it installed there.

Comment: I have used `Clear-Content` recently on some logs, without restarting the service that was writing the log. I obeserved that the service kept writing the log soon after I emptied it with `Clear-Content`. My concern was to know the 'proper' usage of this cmdlet, so for e.g. whether a recycle or start/stop of the application from Windows' IIS administrative tool would be necessary after emptying the log and recuperating +20gb of disk space. Or can this step be skipped?

Comment: Ah. IIS. Unfortunately I don't have a server with IIS installed so I can't test it